# Cannot mount ubuntu mate arm on /dev/loop0

Tags: mount, mate, arm, raspberrypi

I'm trying to customize ubuntu mate image for raspberry pi, by adding some software, which needs to be installed on OS install.

However, when trying to mount with command:

```
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu_mate_arm.img mnt/
```

(I tried also with -t option)

I get an error:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Here is output of

```
dmesg | tail


[ 7642.544485] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 7648.172015] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[ 7661.426211] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.426234] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock
[ 7661.426579] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.426592] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
[ 7661.426804] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.426815] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock
[ 7661.427013] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.427024] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
```

Also, I'm trying this on raspberry pi, using same OS.

If I run losetup first and then mount

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 ubuntu_mate_arm.img
sudo mount /dev/loop0 mnt/
```

I still get an error, but now output of dmesg is

```
[ 7661.426211] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.426234] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock
[ 7661.426579] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.426592] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
[ 7661.426804] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.426815] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock
[ 7661.427013] F2FS-fs (loop0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x0)
[ 7661.427024] F2FS-fs (loop0): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
```

I am using this image https://ubuntu-mate.r.worldssl.net/raspberry-pi/ubuntu-mate-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz

What am I doing wrong?